# speedup loading select options from sql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have an add item form where I have some inputs and 4 selects, every time I click an add/edit record button, it takes about 2-3s to load the form with all possible values to fill out. I'm wondering **if there is any way to make load select options faster from sql database?** (like query caching or other ways that I may not know). This is an example of mechanism I use for loading select options:

**JS:**

```
loadSelectOptions("tab1"); //1600 options
loadSelectOptions("tab2"); //1200
loadSelectOptions("tab3"); //400
loadSelectOptions("tab4"); //100

function loadSelectOptions(elmId) {
    $.post( 
        "queries.php",
        {getValues:elmId},
        function(data) {
            $("#"+elmId).empty();
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                $("#"+elmId).append(data[i]);
            };
            $("#"+elmId).selectpicker("refresh");
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

**PHP (queries.php):**

```
if (isset($_POST["getValues"]) && (in_array($_POST["getValues"], array("tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4")))) {
    $table = $_POST["getValues"];
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM {$table} WHERE active='Y' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $selectValues = array();
    $selectValues[] = "<option value=0> [Select a value] </option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $selectValues[] =  "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
    }   
    echo json_encode($selectValues);
}
```

Please advise how can I simplify this mechanism. I also have another form for adding new select options to database (for admin), so it should be able to recognize when an option list should be refreshed (like a flag for list changed or something else for a caching mechanism). I have some draft thoughts about solving this issue like maybe load to a JS array and read later from it, but I don't want to make this to much complicated than it should be.

Comment: You should clarify.  Is it taking 2-3 seconds just to fetch the data from the database? Or is that the total time including both fetching the data and rendering that data in the DOM?

Comment: It's all together, up to the line `$("#"+elmId).selectpicker("refresh");`

Comment: Fetching the data likely isn't what's taking the bulk of the time. Doing thousands of DOM manipulations is.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things in your example than can be improved upon, I'll first give a brief overview.

1) Typically a select box is not the most optimal UI choice when dealing with large data sets

2) JSON encoding and decoding html like you are from the php script is inefficient / slow, as json has to escape all the html and quote characters.

3) Rather than constructing an array of results to return and then constructing the html client side, it is normally faster to create the html string server side, depending on what type of clients are loading your pages. (This is a somewhat controversial topic, rendering html server vs client side, so you can decide your own stance).

To solve 1, I recommend finding a better ui alternative, such as a search box or similar which can dynamically filter data (thus reducing your data set and the amount of loading time).

To solve 2, don't json encode html, just make your script output the html directly and use that text response as html on your client. This also solves 3.

You can change your php to do the following:

```
echo "<option value='0'>[Select a Value]</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}
```

And then change your javascript to:

```
$.post( 
    "queries.php",
    {getValues:elmId},
    function(data) {
        $("#"+elmId).empty();
        $("#"+elmId).html(data);
        $("#"+elmId).selectpicker("refresh");
    }
);
```

Make sure that the content-type response header of your php script is `text/html` or jquery's ajax call might try to interpret it as json, it is `text/html` by default so if you aren't setting it to `application/json` don't worry.

Additionally, it is better to use a `GET` request in this context rather than a `POST` request, to follow traditional http REST practices, you can read more about this online.

The other solution would be to make your php script only return data, and not pseudo html strings.

For example, your php could become

```
$options = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($options, array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']));
}

echo json_encode($options);
```

And then your javascript could become

```
$.post( 
    "queries.php",
    {getValues:elmId},
    function(data) {
        $("#"+elmId).empty();
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            var option = data[i];
            var html = "<option value='"+option.id+"'>"+option.name+"</option>";
            $("#"+elmId).append(html);
        };
        $("#"+elmId).selectpicker("refresh");
    },
    "json"
);
```

The first option will increase script execution speed (eliminate json encode on html), network performance a little bit(remove unnecessary json formatting from the response), and client performance (get html directly, no looping over an array).

The second option will increase network performance more, but won't perform as well on the client, I suggest trying both and seeing which works better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did some testing on FF and Chrome:  (1) My way - FF=2.90s; CH=1.50s; (2) Your 1st option - FF=2.50s; CH=1.10s; (3) Your 2nd option- FF=2.80s; CH=1.50s. The best is your first option and yes, this isn't a problem with fetching from database, rather with select rendering and this testing shows that Chrome does this much better. I guess I have to probably change the select which I'm using now (bootstrap-select) for let say select2. Do you think it's a good choice?

Comment: @felixRo The second option being slower demonstrates what I meant when I said that constructing the html server side is typically faster than client side, especially if you expect to have mobile clients or other slow clients. You also have to realize that in a real world scenario the size of the script output might be a bottleneck on network performance trying to download the file.

Comment: @felixRo I recommend not using a typical select box at all, actually. I suggest finding or creating a ui widget which will allow you to select filters and filter the returned dataset, and then limit the number of results you return. In a real world scenario it's doubtful a user will sift through more than 100 options anyway, so find a way to filter it. Think about it like this, how often do people go to the second, third, fourth, or more page of a google search?

Comment: yes, you're right, but this is what a group of users want to have, to be able to choose all values from the dataset. I can't think of any rules for filtering the returning dataset. This select which I'm using now, has a live search and has a view options limit, but it renders all of them. At least I know what is causing this behavior and I know how it can be improved for little faster passing dataset from the server side. There is also this flag for activate/deactivate an option and the sql query uses this,so I think users have make it a better use of this flag :)